# Quorum Geth Folder (chaindata, lightchaindata, nodes, LOCK, transactions.rlp), Quorum Raft State (ldb, log, CURRENT, LOCK, LOG, MANIFEST)

Tags: quorum

There are many folders and files generated when I created my Quorum nodes.

Quorum geth folder:

1. chaindata
2. lightchaindata
3. nodes
4. LOCK
5. nodekey
6. transactions.rlp

Quorum Raft State:

1. 000002.ldb
2. 000003.log
3. CURRENT
4. LOCK
5. LOG
6. MANIFEST-000004

raft-snap folder:

1. Multiple *.snap files

raft-wal:

1. *.wal file
2. tmp file

Many of these files are binary files. May I know what these files are and its purpose?